# How do I find no repetition probability with letters and numbers together?

Tags: probability

The question says this "A company manufactures license plates. Each plate gets a number, then two letters, followed by four more numbers. If the digits are not allowed to repeat, how many total license plates can be made?"

Presumably the number are from 0 to 9, and the letters are from A to Z. But there are only 10 numbers, and 26 letters. How do I find probability for the entire license plate when there are separate denominators?

Comment: You are asked to count the cases.  How many options for the first slot?  How many for the second? And so on.

Comment: Note: usually license plates have restrictions.  Can't have both $0$ and $O$ for instance.  Not sure if you left those off or if, for this problem, there aren't any restrictions.

Comment: Seeing as how it wasn't implied, and most of my math tries to ignore that for simplicity reasons, I doubt that restriction is part of the problem.

Comment: By "digits" not repeating, you presumably mean *letters* not repeating because there is only one numeral. Then what is the significance of "two letters, followed by four more letters" ? Why not just $6$ letters not repeating ?

Comment: How many ways are there of filling out the two letters? How many ways are there of filling out the five digits, given that you can only use any digit once? These are both well-known combinatoric calculations. Futher, they are independent of each other. Your choice of a particular pair of letters does not influence in any way what numbers you can choose, and vice versa. So you can have any choice of letters alongside any allowed choice of numbers. So what does not mean about the total number of choices?